# Making subclass of list

Tags: r, r-s3

I have the following code

```
obj <- list(list(a=4,f=5,g=5),list(a=44,f=54,g=54))
class(obj) <- "mysubclass"

class(obj[1])
class(obj[2])
class(obj[1:2])
class(obj)
```

resulting in:

```
> class(obj[1])
[1] "list"
> class(obj[2])
[1] "list"
> class(obj[1:2])
[1] "list"
> class(obj)
[1] "mysubclass"
```

What would be proper solution to not lose the class by subsetting? FOr example, `class(obj[1:2])` results in `mysubclass` and still behaves as a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the generic `[` method is stripping off the `class` attribute. To avoid this, you could just define your own generic for `mysubclass`, i.e.

```
## Answer suggested by Petr Matousu
## Based on simple.list method
'[.mysubclass' = function(x, i, ...) {
    structure(NextMethod("["), class = class(x))
 }
```

Or

```
'[.mysubclass' = function(x, i, j, ..., drop=TRUE) {
    ## Store the class attribute
    cl = class(x)
    ## Pass your object to the next method
    y = NextMethod('[')
    ## Update the class and return
    class(y) = cl
    y
}
```

Your examples now work as expected. You should also look at:

- `help('[')`
- `methods('[')`