# subclass of `list` using S3 classes in R?

Tags: r, subclass

I'd like to make a subclass of list. As in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284005/making-subclass-of-list), I'll need to define a custom method for `[`.

What other methods do I need to make so that my list subclass does not lose its subclass when users manipulate it? `Filter`, I think.

This gets me a few more functions that operate on lists:

```
> methods(class = "list")
[1] all.equal     as.data.frame coerce        escape        Ops           relist        select        within
```

But I don't think any of those return new lists that should have the same type as the old one.

Which am I missing?

Comment: Since `Filter` uses `[` internally, if you define your custom `[` method I doubt you would need to touch `Filter`.

Comment: So maybe just `[`.